# How to make a phone call in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, phone-call

Is there a way to make a phone call in Java EE? Making a call, ending it, etc.

Just like we can SMS using some sites for free like [way2sms](http://www.way2sms.com), is there a way that i can make a phone call for free?

Comment: Are you talking about Java on mobile phones (Java ME or (almost Java on) Android)? Or about Java on the Desktop/Server (Java SE/EE)?

Answer (score 2):

Well given that there are VOIP systems out there, which simply use a network protocol like SIP, all you really need to do is find a SIP library for java, and yes what you're trying to do can technically be done. For free? Depends on if you can find a VOIP provider that gives you free calls. My guess is no.

Comment: can you suggest some library ?

Comment: 'fraid not. I don't know of any. This is just a high-level "yes, probably" answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) provides APIs to handle voice calls, VoIP and SMS. They use RESTful APIs, so it should easily be usable from Java as well.

They don't actually provide free services, but their [prices might be cheap enough](http://www.twilio.com/pricing/).

Comment: Java does not have an inbuilt system to handle this ?

Comment: @program-o-steve: not that I know of. I'm not aware of *any* language that has that built-in. It *is* a pretty specialized feature.

Comment: @program-o-steve: did you try to Google that?